# What are the general forms for type ascription in Agda?

Tags: agda, agda-mode

Background: I'm working through Prabakhar Ragde's ["Logic and Computation Intertwined"](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eplragde/flaneries/LACI/), a totally fantastic introduction to computational intuitionistic logic. In his last chapter, he walks through some basics using Agda. I've successfully installed Agda and managed to twist emacs' arm (it took a lot of arm-twisting!) to get agda-mode working fairly well, but I feel that I'm missing a summary of the various type ascription forms in Agda.

Specifically, working through a proof in Agda without my head exploding requires a fair amount of type ascription--Let's just say this has this type for now, okay?--and I find myself missing the ability to associate types with names in a uniform way. I now know about two ways of doing this, but I feel as though I'm missing a more general one.

- Method 1: When using a "where" form, you can use a double-line specification to perform type ascription.
- Method 2: When using an explicit lambda, I can use parens and a colon to ascribe a type to an identifier.

The following illustrates both of these (using definitions of `or` and negation that are simple but not included, sorry):

```
ex9 : ∀ (A B : Set) → ¬ (¬ (or A (¬ A)))
ex9 A B aornotaimpliesbottom = aornotaimpliesbottom (or-intro-2 nota)
  where nota : ¬ (A)
        nota = λ (a : A) → aornotaimpliesbottom (or-intro-1 a)
```

Method 1 is used to specify the type of `nota`, and method 2 is used to specify the type of `nota`'s argument.

Here's the question, though: what if I want to use type ascription in an "expression" position? For instance, what if I wanted to specify the type of the term `(or-intro-1 a)` ? I could use a "where" clause to pull it out into its own binding, but .... ooh, actually, that doesn't seem to work; embedding a 'where' into a lambda is not working as expected. Oh! It looks like "let" works there. Okay, anyway, question remains: is there a lighter-weight way to specify the type of an expression inline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define inline type annotation as follows:

```
infixl 0 _∋_
_∋_ : ∀{i}(A : Set i) → A → A
A ∋ x = x
```

Or import it from the standard library:

```
open import Function using (_∋_)
```

Then `A ∋ exp` works as an inline type annotation on any expression. For example, in your code as:

```
nota = λ (a : A) → aornotaimpliesbottom (or A (¬ A) ∋ or-intro-1 a)
```

You can also insert inline type annotation, or effectively query the type of an expression which is already in your code, by first inserting a hole like this:

```
nota = λ (a : A) → aornotaimpliesbottom (? ∋ or-intro-1 a)
```

Then hitting `C-c-s` while in the hole, which fills the hole using default inference.

It's also good to remember that `let` is syntactically more flexible than `where`. You can put `let` inside any expression, but `where` only works at binding scopes (at top level, immediately under module declarations, or immediately in function right hand sides).

Comment: OMG, of course! I keep forgetting that in a language like Agda, you can write this kind of type operation as a simple abstraction. I'm trapped in classical programming: no, that would have to be a macro. Cool!